# Reverse for 'students' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I have seen several related questions on this subject, but none have helped solve my problem so far.

I created a project "mysite" and an app within this project, aptly called "app". mysite.urls looks like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('app.urls', namespace='app')),
]
```

app.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^hello/$', views.students),
]
```

app.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, "base.html")

def students(request):
    return render(request, "students.html")
```

app.templates.base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My site</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My site</h1>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'app:students' %}">Students</a>
    </li>
<ul>
<p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
<!-- {% endblock %} -->
</body>
</html>
```

The django error message indicates that it has something to do with the line

```
<a href="{% url 'app:students' %}">Students</a>
```

but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [Have you tried reading the docs?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't named `app`'s urls.

```
# app.urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^hello/$', views.students, name="students"),
]
```

Comment: @user3010617 Glad it helped. Please, do mark this answer as *accepted answer* by clicking that tick mark on the left.